# Can't debug my Xamarin Code-Base

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, windows-10

Iam new to Xamarin but i know building Applications with VS and C#. I started a small Android Project and got some problems with debugging. My Solution contains two Projects:

1. Android Project (for the Android-App)
2. Portable Library (for Business-Logic, thought this could be clever if i try iOS App later)

If i start the Application the pre-defined Click counter works well. But if i use breakpoint and step through code, i can't step throug portable library methods. I just know it from windows forms. There i can easily step through all code in my solution.

Visual Studio tells me: Border is not in Modul. Can't find current Stackborder in loaded Modul.

Is there something wrong with this project architecture? Or iam missing some options for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alone! - This is a common issue with Xamarin 4. There is at the moment no general solution. Maybe [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27308/debugger-doesnt-work-frame-not-in-module) can help you. You can also try [this solution](https://matheusandcode.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/xamarin-android-frame-not-in-module-error-when-debugging/). There are some Tickets open in Bugzilla, so I think this will be fixed in one of the next updates. Stay tuned!

Comment: Ok then i still waiting and hope this get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a bug in the latest stable version. I already reported it when it was still alpha.